# Emails with HTML going to spam

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have my app deployed and the problem is that, i need to send confirmation emails with designs so i used `html` like so:

```
    await transport.sendMail({
        from: process.env.INFO_EMAIL,
        to: email,
        subject: 'ანგარიშის დადასტურება',
        html: htmlStringContainingLink
    });
```

and this is my transporter code (i use zoho):

```
const transport = createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 587 : 465,
    secureConnection: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.INFO_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.INFO_EMAILPASS
    }
});
```

whenever i change `html:` to `text:` it does not go to spam anymore, what should i do?